# No context holder when use partitioner

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm quite new in Spring Batch and probably that's reason why i have such a question, but anyway.
I want to use partitioner so that it splits work between threads(user per thread). I followed book(the definitive guide to spring batch) and got

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope`

I tried various tutorials to solve it but they couldn't help.
There is code i use

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@Import(BatchConfig.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        final JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        final Job job = (Job) context.getBean("partitionerJob");
        log.info("Starting the batch job");
        try {
            final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addString("userId", "123,456,789").toJobParameters());
            log.info("Job Status : {}", execution.getStatus());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Job failed {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Slf4j
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Job partitionerJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionerJob")
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step masterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionerStep")
                .partitioner(slaveStep(null).getName(), userPartitioner(null))
                .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() {
        return 
          this.stepBuilderFactory.get("partStep").tasklet(tasklet(null)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[userId]}") String userId) {
        return ((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            log.info("Current thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and i process userId=" + userId);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        });
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler() {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        partitionHandler.setStep(slaveStep(null));
        partitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        partitionHandler.setGridSize(3);
        return partitionHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public UserPartitioner userPartitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters[userId]}") String userId) {
        UserPartitioner userPartitioner = new UserPartitioner();
        userPartitioner.setUserList(Stream.of(userId.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return userPartitioner;
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(3);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

}
```

```
public class UserPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    private static final String PARTITION_KEY = "partition";

    private List<String> userList;

    public void setUserList(List<String> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionContext = new HashMap<>(gridSize);

        int i = 0;
        for (String userId: userList) {
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.put("userId", userId);
            partitionContext .put(PARTITION_KEY + i, context);
            i++;
        }

        return partitionContext;
    }
}
```

On the internet i found lots of complaining along with solutions regarding that error, but often that error has different causes.
I tried to remove @StepScope and setAutoProxy(true), but no luck. 
Probably i'm missing something but i don't see what exactly.

Here is full stack trace

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-11 13:53:46.474  INFO 28557 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on sts with PID 28557 (/home/sts/IdeaProjects/demo/target/classes started by sts in /home/sts/IdeaProjects/demo)
2020-02-11 13:53:46.478  INFO 28557 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-11 13:53:47.352  INFO 28557 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', username='sa'
2020-02-11 13:53:47.780  WARN 28557 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partitionerJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'partitionerJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'masterStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
2020-02-11 13:53:47.781  INFO 28557 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb'
2020-02-11 13:53:47.799  INFO 28557 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-11 13:53:47.804 ERROR 28557 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partitionerJob' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'partitionerJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'masterStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:42) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'partitionerJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'masterStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'masterStep' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/BatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'masterStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd.masterStep(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig.partitionerJob(BatchConfig.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd.CGLIB$partitionerJob$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9cf674b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd.partitionerJob(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'masterStep' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.slaveStep': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig.masterStep(BatchConfig.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd.CGLIB$masterStep$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9cf674b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.BatchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3396cdcd.masterStep(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Actually you can reproduce this error locally using just given code, just generate project via spring initializr with added spring-batch and lombok.

Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S.
Maven pom (probably will be useful)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct to add `StepScope` on a `Step` bean:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Step slaveStep(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[userId]}") String userId) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("partStep").tasklet(((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        log.info("Current thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and i process userId=" + userId);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    })).build();
}
```

Because this means that the Step bean should be created only when the Step is active.. but to be active, the step should be created first, but it should be created only when it is active.. So what you need to do is to extract the tasklet of the step as a Step scoped bean and configure the step with that tasklet. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public Step slaveStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("partStep").tasklet(tasklet(null)).build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[userId]}") String userId) {
    return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        log.info("Current thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and i process userId=" + userId);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it works now. The only question now why tasklet doesn't work(log lines don't appear in console) although job marked as "Completed". I understand that's diffirent question. If anwser is short i'd be glad to see it:)

Comment: Log level configured fine, i see logs with level "info" from other places. Programm even doesn't stop execution on breakpoint inside slave tasklet. I also modified programm so that it throws an exception inside tasklet. But job still finishes with status "Completed". Don't understand why :/

Comment: It's oke, i've figured out what's wrong. Other threads swallowed an exception that was thrown inside partitioner so that exception was not displayed on console. I'll edit provided code so that people from future can use it for experiments. Many thanks again to Mahmoud!